# insert Java char into MySQL char

Tags: java, mysql

I want to insert a Java char into a MySQL char column , but it gives a Data Truncation error.

The size of the MySQL char column is 1 , and the Java char being inserted is 'Q'

I am not getting the issue , whereas the value being inserted is a proper value , is it that the MySQL char datatype is represented separately , and the Java char is not compatible with it.

Any inputs are appreciated.

Thanks
Vivek

Comment: can you show your query example what exactly you do

Comment: What character encoding sets are you using?

Comment: insert into <tbl_nm> values(?)

and replacing the ? , with Java char 'Q'

Comment: Pelshoff : that's what I think i need to do , currently am not using any character encoding sets. But not sure about how to do it.. the encoding for the char datatype in MySQl is UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

check with the byte code in mysql and java here is some link so conform with it

[MySQL Data Truncation Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73109/mysql-data-truncation-error/73397#73397)