# MySQL: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '2006-10-01 02:22:44'

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I'm getting the following exception updating a row using MySQL via JDBC:

> com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '2006-10-01 02:22:44'

The column is defined as:

> '`created_on_service` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL'

There are no indexes or foreign keys on that column.

Obviously it's not a problem with data type. I have values in that table from both before and after that datetime. I also have values with times both before and after 2:22 AM.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73109/mysql-data-truncation-error

Comment: That link is about text data, specifically multi-byte character sets. It's not applicable. I did search StackOverflow for similar questions before I posted, but no luck I'm afraid.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Solved it.

Turns out that the 1st of October 2006 in South Australia was the start of daylight savings. Clocks get set forward one hour at 2.00am, so there was no 2:22am on that date: it went straight from 2:00am to 3:01am.

I'll change the db timezone to UTC, which should solve this issue.

Comment: Wanted to know as what else options do we have, if it's not feasible to change db-timezone. Nevertheless, you really saved lot of brain tiredness by pointing out the issue.

Answer (score 5):

I fixed the same problem (`com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'perev_start_time' at row 1`) by upgrading my MySQL connector JAR, and copying the mysql.jar to the Tomcat lib directory.

The version of MySQL Server is 5.6 and the MySQL connector is `mysql-connector-java-5.1.30-bin.jar`.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  In general, follow-up questions should not be posted as answers, but instead [asked separately](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).  Feel free to link back to this question, however.

Comment: This does not look like a new question

Answer (score 3):

We upgraded MySQL server but didnt upgrade the mysql connector jar. We encountered this issue. Later I figured out it was due to the old jar. I upgraded it and this issue went away.

Answer (score 3):

My problem was caused by DST, too. I've fixed it by changing column data type from `timestamp` to `datetime`. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2934271/1192987) describes the difference, in short:

- **timestamp** stores time as [Unix epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), so converts it to/from UTC according to server's time zone. Once you change server time zone, you have different interpretation for `INSERT`/`UPDATE` and different `SELECT` results. Some time points are invalid due to DST;
- **datetime** stores time as is, regardless of server time zone. When passing UTC time, any time is valid (there are no DST "holes").

Note: you may still have to deal with "missing" time. This approach just shifts responsibility from DB level to application level.

See also: [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html)  for TIMESTAMP vs DATETIME

Answer (score 0):

You did not show exact update SQL. But may be you forget the date part

The correct format is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format

Date value should be in following format 2011-11-01 12:32:01

Comment: I'm using JDBC, so the exact SQL is obscured, but judging from the error message I'm getting, the value is already in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format.

Comment: For Java, the real format using a 24 hour clock should be: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"