# Daylight Saving Time MySql unable to add 1 day

Tags: mysql, timestamp, dst

Adding 1 day to the MySQL EST TIMESTAMP column error if it lands in between the daylight adjustment hour. Any way around it other than catch exception and then add an extra hour?

The insert query adds a day: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 DAY

That gives error when it lands on an invalid day light time of the day:

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '2022-03-13 02:29:00' for column 'revoked' at row 1

The column is EST which is consistent with other TIMESTAMP columns in our database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL: Data truncation: Incorrect datetime value: '2006-10-01 02:22:44'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564365/mysql-data-truncation-incorrect-datetime-value-2006-10-01-022244)

Comment: Specifically, see the answers about updating your MySQL Connector.

Comment: hmm.. changing to UTC is not an option yet, and mine is already upgraded to  mysql-connector-java:8.0.28