# MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Out of range value for column 'column' at row 1

Tags: java, mysql, database

I am using Java and MySQL. I am trying to insert a value into a table.

When I insert, I get this exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Out of 
range value for column 'idPxxx' at row 1
```

Only 5% of inserts produces this exception, others work. What does the error mean and how do I prevent it?

Comment: see this Question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73109/mysql-data-truncation-error

Comment: Maybe you have one type in DB and data inserted is of another type.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It means that the data you are storing in `idPxxx` doesn't fit. For example a string might be too long, or a number too large.

What is the datatype of `idPxxx`? And what are you trying to store in it?

Comment: Thank you, that's what I thought but this problem happens only to 5% of data sent, and when I repeat the test the same happens.

Comment: @Khaledez how come you didn't answer the questions I asked in my answer?

Comment: Datatype is `Unsigned INT(64)` and I'm trying to insert value `2000`.
Again I'm inserting into `X` table which has a foreign key `idPxxx` from `Y` table and the value of `idPxxx` is existed in `Y` table.

Comment: @Khaledez as an experiment, try changing the datatype to signed, and try the load. Perhaps you have some negative number and don't know it? Another possibility is that the java connector is not handling 64 bit numbers correctly, so it's truncating them to 32 bit, which can turn them negative and that in turn is failing since the column is listed as unsigned.

Comment: thank you, I discovered that the problem is caused by another problem that sets the value of `idPxxx` to -2, after I've changed the data type to `SIGNED`

Answer (score 6):

##### How to reproduce this exception on the MySQL console:

```
mysql> create table penguin (mydecimal decimal(9,8));
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> insert into penguin values (1234.1234);
Query OK, 1 row affected, 1 warning (0.01 sec)

mysql> show warnings;
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                            |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1264 | Out of range value for column 'mydecimal' at row 1 |
+---------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from penguin;
+------------+
| mydecimal  |
+------------+
| 9.99999999 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

You tried to cram 1234 into a column that could take maximum `9.99999999`, because `DECIMAL(9, 8)` means 9 digits in total, 8 of them are for digits after the *decimal point*.  Notice the row is still inserted.

##### You can get the MySQL console to prevent this conversion using *strict mode*:

```
mysql> set sql_mode=STRICT_ALL_TABLES;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into penguin values (5678.5678);
ERROR 1264 (22003): Out of range value for column 'mydecimal' at row 1
```

The insert command failed in attempting add a second row to `penguin`:

```
mysql> select * from penguin;
+------------+
| mydecimal  |
+------------+
| 9.99999999 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

### Solutions

1. *Expand* the size of the data type in your column to accept the value you put in there.
2. *Shrink* the size of the value that you are trying to cram into a small data type.

Answer (score 2):

To me the problem was of unsigned datatype, removing the flag has fixed my problem.

Comment: I too was using unsigned data type, and was passing negative value, which was caught because of this error.

Answer (score 1):

This type of error message can shown for different scenario.

**I have identified one reason :**

In my case the problem that I had defined the

> double (17,17)

... that mean 17 digits and 17 decimals so it rests 0 for the integer (!).

With

> double(24,12)

everything is OK