# MySQL data truncation for Unicode characters

Tags: java, mysql, unicode

I have mysql 5.0 configured to store UTF-8. I have a column with datatype as `longtext`. I tried storing this and it gets stored with no problem (MySQL is able to store UTF-8):

> Τὴ γλῶσσα μοῦ ἔδωσαν ἑλληνικὴ τὸ σπίτι φτωχικὸ στὶς ἀμμουδιὲς τοῦ
>   Ὁμήρου. Μονάχη ἔγνοια ἡ γλῶσσα μου στὶς ἀμμουδιὲς τοῦ Ὁμήρου. ἀπὸ τὸ
>   Ἄξιον ἐστί τοῦ Ὀδυσσέα Ἐλύτη

Just for testing I tried storing this:

> Sanskrit: काचं शक्नोम्यत्तुम् । नोपहिनस्ति माम् ॥ Sanskrit (standard
>   transcription): kācaṃ śaknomyattum; nopahinasti mām. Classical Greek:
>   ὕαλον ϕαγεῖν δύναμαι· τοῦτο οὔ με βλάπτει. Greek (monotonic): Μπορώ να
>   φάω σπασμένα γυαλιά χωρίς να πάθω τίποτα. Greek (polytonic): Μπορῶ νὰ
>   φάω σπασμένα γυαλιὰ χωρὶς νὰ πάθω τίποτα.  Etruscan: (NEEDED) Latin:
>   Vitrum edere possum; mihi non nocet. Old French: Je puis mangier del
>   voirre. Ne me nuit. French: Je peux manger du verre, ça ne me fait pas
>   mal. Provençal / Occitan: Pòdi manjar de veire, me nafrariá pas.
>   Québécois: J'peux manger d'la vitre, ça m'fa pas mal. Walloon: Dji pou
>   magnî do vêre, çoula m' freut nén må.  Champenois: (NEEDED)  Lorrain:
>   (NEEDED) Picard: Ch'peux mingi du verre, cha m'foé mie n'ma. 
>   Corsican/Corsu: (NEEDED)  Jèrriais: (NEEDED) Kreyòl Ayisyen (Haitï):
>   Mwen kap manje vè, li pa blese'm. Basque: Kristala jan dezaket, ez dit
>   minik ematen. Catalan / Català: Puc menjar vidre, que no em fa mal.
>   Spanish: Puedo comer vidrio, no me hace daño. Aragonés: Puedo minchar
>   beire, no me'n fa mal .  Aranés: (NEEDED)  Mallorquín: (NEEDED)
>   Galician: Eu podo xantar cristais e non cortarme. European Portuguese:
>   Posso comer vidro, não me faz mal. Brazilian Portuguese (8): Posso
>   comer vidro, não me machuca. Caboverdiano/Kabuverdianu (Cape Verde):
>   M' podê cumê vidru, ca ta maguâ-m'. Papiamentu: Ami por kome glas anto
>   e no ta hasimi daño. Italian: Posso mangiare il vetro e non mi fa
>   male. Milanese: Sôn bôn de magnà el véder, el me fa minga mal. Roman:
>   Me posso magna' er vetro, e nun me fa male. Napoletano: M' pozz magna'
>   o'vetr, e nun m' fa mal. Venetian: Mi posso magnare el vetro, no'l me
>   fa mae. Zeneise (Genovese): Pòsso mangiâ o veddro e o no me fà mâ.
>   Sicilian: Puotsu mangiari u vitru, nun mi fa mali.  Campinadese
>   (Sardinia): (NEEDED)  Lugudorese (Sardinia): (NEEDED) Romansch
>   (Grischun): Jau sai mangiar vaider, senza che quai fa donn a mai. 
>   Romany / Tsigane: (NEEDED) Romanian: Pot să mănânc sticlă și ea nu mă
>   rănește. Esperanto: Mi povas manĝi vitron, ĝi ne damaĝas min. 
>   Pictish: (NEEDED)  Breton: (NEEDED) Cornish: Mý a yl dybry gwéder hag
>   éf ny wra ow ankenya. Welsh: Dw i'n gallu bwyta gwydr, 'dyw e ddim yn
>   gwneud dolur i mi. Manx Gaelic: Foddym gee glonney agh cha jean eh
>   gortaghey mee. Old Irish (Ogham): ᚛᚛ᚉᚑᚅᚔᚉᚉᚔᚋ ᚔᚈᚔ ᚍᚂᚐᚅᚑ ᚅᚔᚋᚌᚓᚅᚐ᚜ Old
>   Irish (Latin): Con·iccim ithi nglano. Ním·géna. Irish: Is féidir liom
>   gloinne a ithe. Ní dhéanann sí dochar ar bith dom. Ulster Gaelic:
>   Ithim-sa gloine agus ní miste damh é. Scottish Gaelic: S urrainn dhomh
>   gloinne ithe; cha ghoirtich i mi. Anglo-Saxon (Runes):
>   ᛁᚳ᛫ᛗᚨᚷ᛫ᚷᛚᚨᛋ᛫ᛖᚩᛏᚪᚾ᛫ᚩᚾᛞ᛫ᚻᛁᛏ᛫ᚾᛖ᛫ᚻᛖᚪᚱᛗᛁᚪᚧ᛫ᛗᛖ᛬ Anglo-Saxon (Latin): Ic mæg
>   glæs eotan ond hit ne hearmiað me. Middle English: Ich canne glas eten
>   and hit hirtiþ me nouȝt. English: I can eat glass and it doesn't hurt
>   me. English (IPA): [aɪ kæn iːt glɑːs ænd ɪt dɐz nɒt hɜːt miː]
>   (Received Pronunciation) English (Braille):
>   ⠊⠀⠉⠁⠝⠀⠑⠁⠞⠀⠛⠇⠁⠎⠎⠀⠁⠝⠙⠀⠊⠞⠀⠙⠕⠑⠎⠝⠞⠀⠓⠥⠗⠞⠀⠍⠑ Jamaican: Mi kian niam glas han
>   i neba hot mi. Lalland Scots / Doric: Ah can eat gless, it disnae hurt
>   us.  Glaswegian: (NEEDED) Gothic (4):   ̈, 
>      . Old Norse (Runes): ᛖᚴ ᚷᛖᛏ ᛖᛏᛁ ᚧ
>   ᚷᛚᛖᚱ ᛘᚾ ᚦᛖᛋᛋ ᚨᚧ ᚡᛖ ᚱᚧᚨ ᛋᚨᚱ Old Norse (Latin): Ek get etið gler án þess
>   að verða sár. Norsk / Norwegian (Nynorsk): Eg kan eta glas utan å
>   skada meg. Norsk / Norwegian (Bokmål): Jeg kan spise glass uten å
>   skade meg. Føroyskt / Faroese: Eg kann eta glas, skaðaleysur. Íslenska
>   / Icelandic: Ég get etið gler án þess að meiða mig. Svenska / Swedish:
>   Jag kan äta glas utan att skada mig. Dansk / Danish: Jeg kan spise
>   glas, det gør ikke ondt på mig. Sønderjysk: Æ ka æe glass uhen at det
>   go mæ naue. Frysk / Frisian: Ik kin glês ite, it docht me net sear.
>   Nederlands / Dutch: Ik kan glas eten, het doet mĳ geen kwaad.
>   Kirchröadsj/Bôchesserplat: Iech ken glaas èèse, mer 't deet miech jing
>   pieng. Afrikaans: Ek kan glas eet, maar dit doen my nie skade nie.
>   Lëtzebuergescht / Luxemburgish: Ech kan Glas iessen, daat deet mir nët
>   wei. Deutsch / German: Ich kann Glas essen, ohne mir zu schaden.
>   Ruhrdeutsch: Ich kann Glas verkasematuckeln, ohne dattet mich wat
>   jucken tut. Langenfelder Platt: Isch kann Jlaas kimmeln, uuhne datt
>   mich datt weh dääd. Lausitzer Mundart ("Lusatian"): Ich koann Gloos
>   assn und doas dudd merr ni wii. Odenwälderisch: Iech konn glaasch
>   voschbachteln ohne dass es mir ebbs daun doun dud. Sächsisch / Saxon:
>   'sch kann Glos essn, ohne dass'sch mer wehtue. Pfälzisch: Isch konn
>   Glass fresse ohne dasses mer ebbes ausmache dud. Schwäbisch / Swabian:
>   I kå Glas frässa, ond des macht mr nix! Deutsch (Voralberg): I ka glas
>   eassa, ohne dass mar weh tuat. Bayrisch / Bavarian: I koh Glos esa,
>   und es duard ma ned wei. Allemannisch: I kaun Gloos essen, es tuat ma
>   ned weh. Schwyzerdütsch (Zürich): Ich chan Glaas ässe, das schadt mir
>   nöd. Schwyzerdütsch (Luzern): Ech cha Glâs ässe, das schadt mer ned. 
>   Plautdietsch: (NEEDED) Hungarian: Meg tudom enni az üveget, nem lesz
>   tőle bajom. Suomi / Finnish: Voin syödä lasia, se ei vahingoita minua.
>   Sami (Northern): Sáhtán borrat lása, dat ii leat bávččas. Erzian: Мон
>   ярсан суликадо, ды зыян эйстэнзэ а ули. Northern Karelian: Mie voin
>   syvvä lasie ta minla ei ole kipie. Southern Karelian: Minä voin syvvä
>   st'oklua dai minule ei ole kibie.  Vepsian: (NEEDED)  Votian: (NEEDED)
>   Livonian: (NEEDED) Estonian: Ma võin klaasi süüa, see ei tee mulle
>   midagi. Latvian: Es varu ēst stiklu, tas man nekaitē. Lithuanian: Aš
>   galiu valgyti stiklą ir jis manęs nežeidžia  Old Prussian: (NEEDED) 
>   Sorbian (Wendish): (NEEDED) Czech: Mohu jíst sklo, neublíží mi.
>   Slovak: Môžem jesť sklo. Nezraní ma. Polska / Polish: Mogę jeść szkło
>   i mi nie szkodzi. Slovenian: Lahko jem steklo, ne da bi mi škodovalo.
>   Croatian: Ja mogu jesti staklo i ne boli me. Serbian (Latin): Ja mogu
>   da jedem staklo. Serbian (Cyrillic): Ја могу да једем стакло.
>   Macedonian: Можам да јадам стакло, а не ме штета. Russian: Я могу есть
>   стекло, оно мне не вредит. Belarusian (Cyrillic): Я магу есці шкло,
>   яно мне не шкодзіць. Belarusian (Lacinka): Ja mahu jeści škło, jano
>   mne ne škodzić. Ukrainian: Я можу їсти скло, і воно мені не зашкодить.
>   Bulgarian: Мога да ям стъкло, то не ми вреди. Georgian: მინას ვჭამ და
>   არა მტკივა. Armenian: Կրնամ ապակի ուտել և ինծի անհանգիստ չըներ։
>   Albanian: Unë mund të ha qelq dhe nuk më gjen gjë. Turkish: Cam
>   yiyebilirim, bana zararı dokunmaz. Turkish (Ottoman): جام ييه بلورم
>   بڭا ضررى طوقونمز Bangla / Bengali: আমি কাঁচ খেতে পারি, তাতে আমার কোনো
>   ক্ষতি হয় না। Marathi: मी काच खाऊ शकतो, मला ते दुखत नाही. Kannada: ನನಗೆ
>   ಹಾನಿ ಆಗದೆ, ನಾನು ಗಜನ್ನು ತಿನಬಹುದು Hindi: मैं काँच खा सकता हूँ और मुझे
>   उससे कोई चोट नहीं पहुंचती. Tamil: நான் கண்ணாடி சாப்பிடுவேன், அதனால்
>   எனக்கு ஒரு கேடும் வராது. Telugu: నేను గాజు తినగలను మరియు అలా చేసినా
>   నాకు ఏమి ఇబ్బంది లేదు Sinhalese: මට වීදුරු කෑමට හැකියි. එයින් මට කිසි
>   හානියක් සිදු නොවේ. Urdu(3): میں کانچ کھا سکتا ہوں اور مجھے تکلیف نہیں
>   ہوتی ۔ Pashto(3): زه شيشه خوړلې شم، هغه ما نه خوږوي Farsi /
>   Persian(3): .من می توانم بدونِ احساس درد شيشه بخورم Arabic(3): أنا
>   قادر على أكل الزجاج و هذا لا يؤلمني.  Aramaic: (NEEDED) Maltese:
>   Nista' niekol il-ħġieġ u ma jagħmilli xejn. Hebrew(3): אני יכול לאכול
>   זכוכית וזה לא מזיק לי. Yiddish(3): איך קען עסן גלאָז און עס טוט מיר
>   נישט װײ.  Judeo-Arabic: (NEEDED)  Ladino: (NEEDED)  Gǝʼǝz: (NEEDED) 
>   Amharic: (NEEDED) Twi: Metumi awe tumpan, ɜnyɜ me hwee. Hausa (Latin):
>   Inā iya taunar gilāshi kuma in gamā lāfiyā. Hausa (Ajami) (2):
>   إِنا إِىَ تَونَر غِلَاشِ كُمَ إِن غَمَا لَافِىَا Yoruba(4): Mo lè je̩
>   dígí, kò ní pa mí lára. Lingala: Nakokí kolíya biténi bya milungi,
>   ekosála ngáí mabé tɛ́. (Ki)Swahili: Naweza kula bilauri na
>   sikunyui. Malay: Saya boleh makan kaca dan ia tidak mencederakan saya.
>   Tagalog: Kaya kong kumain nang bubog at hindi ako masaktan. Chamorro:
>   Siña yo' chumocho krestat, ti ha na'lalamen yo'. Fijian: Au rawa ni
>   kana iloilo, ia au sega ni vakacacani kina. Javanese: Aku isa mangan
>   beling tanpa lara. Burmese: က္ယ္ဝန္‌တော္‌၊က္ယ္ဝန္‌မ
>   မ္ယက္‌စားနုိင္‌သည္‌။ ၎က္ရောင္‌့ ထိခုိက္‌မ္ဟု မရ္ဟိပာ။ (9) Vietnamese
>   (quốc ngữ): Tôi có thể ăn thủy tinh mà không hại gì. Vietnamese (nôm)
>   (4): 些  世 咹 水 晶  空  害 咦 Khmer: ខ្ញុំអាចញុំកញ្ចក់បាន
>   ដោយគ្មានបញ្ហារ Lao: ຂອ້ຍກິນແກ້ວໄດ້ໂດຍທີ່ມັນບໍ່ໄດ້ເຮັດໃຫ້ຂອ້ຍເຈັບ.
>   Thai: ฉันกินกระจกได้ แต่มันไม่ทำให้ฉันเจ็บ Mongolian (Cyrillic): Би
>   шил идэй чадна, надад хортой биш Mongolian (Classic) (5): ᠪᠢ ᠰᠢᠯᠢ
>   ᠢᠳᠡᠶᠦ ᠴᠢᠳᠠᠨᠠ ᠂ ᠨᠠᠳᠤᠷ ᠬᠣᠤᠷᠠᠳᠠᠢ ᠪᠢᠰᠢ  Dzongkha: (NEEDED) Nepali: म काँच
>   खान सक्छू र मलाई केहि नी हुन्‍न् । Tibetan: ཤེལ་སྒོ་ཟ་ནས་ང་ན་གི་མ་རེད།
>   Chinese: 我能吞下玻璃而不伤身体。 Chinese (Traditional): 我能吞下玻璃而不傷身體。
>   Taiwanese(6): Góa ē-tàng chia̍h po-lê, mā bē tio̍h-siong. Japanese:
>   私はガラスを食べられます。それは私を傷つけません。 Korean: 나는 유리를 먹을 수 있어요. 그래도 아프지 않아요
>   Bislama: Mi save kakae glas, hemi no save katem mi. Hawaiian: Hiki
>   iaʻu ke ʻai i ke aniani; ʻaʻole nō lā au e ʻeha. Marquesan: E koʻana e
>   kai i te karahi, mea ʻā, ʻaʻe hauhau. Inuktitut (10): ᐊᓕᒍᖅ ᓂᕆᔭᕌᖓᒃᑯ
>   ᓱᕋᙱᑦᑐᓐᓇᖅᑐᖓ Chinook Jargon: Naika məkmək kakshət labutay, pi weyk ukuk
>   munk-sik nay. Navajo: Tsésǫʼ yishą́ągo bííníshghah dóó doo shił
>   neezgai da.  Cherokee (and Cree, Chickasaw, Cree, Micmac, Ojibwa,
>   Lakota, Náhuatl, Quechua, Aymara, and other American languages):
>   (NEEDED)  Garifuna: (NEEDED)  Gullah: (NEEDED) Lojban: mi kakne le nu
>   citka le blaci .iku'i le se go'i na xrani mi Nórdicg: Ljœr ye caudran
>   créneþ ý jor cẃran.

And I got this:

`com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column`

To be sure that this is not an issue with the length of the text, I stored the full text contained in [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google)... Its length is longer than the text I pasted above... And this works. It got stored without any problem.

Does anyone know what is the problem?

**EDIT :**

How to check that my UTF-8 data is all 3-byte Unicode?

Comment: You seen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/73109/mysql-data-truncation-error which sounds possible with all that unicode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah it seems issue is because of non utf8 content. i able to fit the same text in column with field type: text without this data : ᠪᠢ ᠰᠢᠯᠢ ᠢᠳᠡᠶᠦ ᠴᠢᠳᠠᠨᠠ ᠂ ᠨᠠᠳᠤᠷ ᠬᠣᠤᠷᠠᠳᠠᠢ ᠪᠢᠰᠢ Dzongkha:

Please try to fire below query before executing insert query:

```
set names "utf8";
```

Also add these lines to either my.cnf or my.ini:

```
 [client]
default-character-set=utf8


 [mysql]
 default-character-set=utf8


 [mysqld]
 default-character-set=utf8
 character-set-server=utf8
```

Hope this help.

**Here is the text**

Sanskrit: काचं शक्नोम्यत्तुम् । नोपहिनस्ति माम् ॥ Sanskrit (standard transcription): kācaṃ śaknomyattum; nopahinasti mām. Classical Greek: ὕαλον ϕαγεῖν δύναμαι· τοῦτο οὔ με βλάπτει. Greek (monotonic): Μπορώ να φάω σπασμένα γυαλιά χωρίς να πάθω τίποτα. Greek (polytonic): Μπορῶ νὰ φάω σπασμένα γυαλιὰ χωρὶς νὰ πάθω τίποτα. Etruscan: (NEEDED) Latin: Vitrum edere possum; mihi non nocet. Old French: Je puis mangier del voirre. Ne me nuit. French: Je peux manger du verre, ça ne me fait pas mal. Provençal / Occitan: Pòdi manjar de veire, me nafrariá pas. Québécois: J''peux manger d''la vitre, ça m''fa pas mal. Walloon: Dji pou magnî do vêre, çoula m'' freut nén må. Champenois: (NEEDED) Lorrain: (NEEDED) Picard: Ch''peux mingi du verre, cha m''foé mie n''ma. Corsican/Corsu: (NEEDED) Jèrriais: (NEEDED) Kreyòl Ayisyen (Haitï): Mwen kap manje vè, li pa blese''m. Basque: Kristala jan dezaket, ez dit minik ematen. Catalan / Català: Puc menjar vidre, que no em fa mal. Spanish: Puedo comer vidrio, no me hace daño. Aragonés: Puedo minchar beire, no me''n fa mal . Aranés: (NEEDED) Mallorquín: (NEEDED) Galician: Eu podo xantar cristais e non cortarme. European Portuguese: Posso comer vidro, não me faz mal. Brazilian Portuguese (8): Posso comer vidro, não me machuca. Caboverdiano/Kabuverdianu (Cape Verde): M'' podê cumê vidru, ca ta maguâ-m''. Papiamentu: Ami por kome glas anto e no ta hasimi daño. Italian: Posso mangiare il vetro e non mi fa male. Milanese: Sôn bôn de magnà el véder, el me fa minga mal. Roman: Me posso magna'' er vetro, e nun me fa male. Napoletano: M'' pozz magna'' o''vetr, e nun m'' fa mal. Venetian: Mi posso magnare el vetro, no''l me fa mae. Zeneise (Genovese): Pòsso mangiâ o veddro e o no me fà mâ. Sicilian: Puotsu mangiari u vitru, nun mi fa mali. Campinadese (Sardinia): (NEEDED) Lugudorese (Sardinia): (NEEDED) Romansch (Grischun): Jau sai mangiar vaider, senza che quai fa donn a mai. Romany / Tsigane: (NEEDED) Romanian: Pot să mănânc sticlă și ea nu mă rănește. Esperanto: Mi povas manĝi vitron, ĝi ne damaĝas min. Pictish: (NEEDED) Breton: (NEEDED) Cornish: Mý a yl dybry gwéder hag éf ny wra ow ankenya. Welsh: Dw i''n gallu bwyta gwydr, ''dyw e ddim yn gwneud dolur i mi. Manx Gaelic: Foddym gee glonney agh cha jean eh gortaghey mee. Old Irish (Ogham): ᚛᚛ᚉᚑᚅᚔᚉᚉᚔᚋ ᚔᚈᚔ ᚍᚂᚐᚅᚑ ᚅᚔᚋᚌᚓᚅᚐ᚜ Old Irish (Latin): Con·iccim ithi nglano. Ním·géna. Irish: Is féidir liom gloinne a ithe. Ní dhéanann sí dochar ar bith dom. Ulster Gaelic: Ithim-sa gloine agus ní miste damh é. Scottish Gaelic: S urrainn dhomh gloinne ithe; cha ghoirtich i mi. Anglo-Saxon (Runes): Anglo-Saxon (Latin): Ic mæg glæs eotan ond hit ne hearmiað me. Middle English: Ich canne glas eten and hit hirtiþ me nouȝt. English: I can eat glass and it doesn''t hurt me. English (IPA): [aɪ kæn iːt glɑːs ænd ɪt dɐz nɒt hɜːt miː] (Received Pronunciation) English (Braille): ⠊⠀⠉⠁⠝⠀⠑⠁⠞⠀⠛⠇⠁⠎⠎⠀⠁⠝⠙⠀⠊⠞⠀⠙⠕⠑⠎⠝⠞⠀⠓⠥⠗⠞⠀⠍⠑ Jamaican: Mi kian niam glas han i neba hot mi. Lalland Scots / Doric: Ah can eat gless, it disnae hurt us. Glaswegian: (NEEDED) Gothic (4): Old Norse (Latin): Ek get etið gler án þess að verða sár. Norsk / Norwegian (Nynorsk): Eg kan eta glas utan å skada meg. Norsk / Norwegian (Bokmål): Jeg kan spise glass uten å skade meg. Føroyskt / Faroese: Eg kann eta glas, skaðaleysur. Íslenska / Icelandic: Ég get etið gler án þess að meiða mig. Svenska / Swedish: Jag kan äta glas utan att skada mig. Dansk / Danish: Jeg kan spise glas, det gør ikke ondt på mig. Sønderjysk: Æ ka æe glass uhen at det go mæ naue. Frysk / Frisian: Ik kin glês ite, it docht me net sear. Nederlands / Dutch: Ik kan glas eten, het doet mĳ geen kwaad. Kirchröadsj/Bôchesserplat: Iech ken glaas èèse, mer ''t deet miech jing pieng. Afrikaans: Ek kan glas eet, maar dit doen my nie skade nie. Lëtzebuergescht / Luxemburgish: Ech kan Glas iessen, daat deet mir nët wei. Deutsch / German: Ich kann Glas essen, ohne mir zu schaden. Ruhrdeutsch: Ich kann Glas verkasematuckeln, ohne dattet mich wat jucken tut. Langenfelder Platt: Isch kann Jlaas kimmeln, uuhne datt mich datt weh dääd. Lausitzer Mundart ("Lusatian"): Ich koann Gloos assn und doas dudd merr ni wii. Odenwälderisch: Iech konn glaasch voschbachteln ohne dass es mir ebbs daun doun dud. Sächsisch / Saxon: ''sch kann Glos essn, ohne dass''sch mer wehtue. Pfälzisch: Isch konn Glass fresse ohne dasses mer ebbes ausmache dud. Schwäbisch / Swabian: I kå Glas frässa, ond des macht mr nix! Deutsch (Voralberg): I ka glas eassa, ohne dass mar weh tuat. Bayrisch / Bavarian: I koh Glos esa, und es duard ma ned wei. Allemannisch: I kaun Gloos essen, es tuat ma ned weh. Schwyzerdütsch (Zürich): Ich chan Glaas ässe, das schadt mir nöd. Schwyzerdütsch (Luzern): Ech cha Glâs ässe, das schadt mer ned. Plautdietsch: (NEEDED) Hungarian: Meg tudom enni az üveget, nem lesz tőle bajom. Suomi / Finnish: Voin syödä lasia, se ei vahingoita minua. Sami (Northern): Sáhtán borrat lása, dat ii leat bávččas. Erzian: Мон ярсан суликадо, ды зыян эйстэнзэ а ули. Northern Karelian: Mie voin syvvä lasie ta minla ei ole kipie. Southern Karelian: Minä voin syvvä st''oklua dai minule ei ole kibie. Vepsian: (NEEDED) Votian: (NEEDED) Livonian: (NEEDED) Estonian: Ma võin klaasi süüa, see ei tee mulle midagi. Latvian: Es varu ēst stiklu, tas man nekaitē. Lithuanian: Aš galiu valgyti stiklą ir jis manęs nežeidžia Old Prussian: (NEEDED) Sorbian (Wendish): (NEEDED) Czech: Mohu jíst sklo, neublíží mi. Slovak: Môžem jesť sklo. Nezraní ma. Polska / Polish: Mogę jeść szkło i mi nie szkodzi. Slovenian: Lahko jem steklo, ne da bi mi škodovalo. Croatian: Ja mogu jesti staklo i ne boli me. Serbian (Latin): Ja mogu da jedem staklo. Serbian (Cyrillic): Ја могу да једем стакло. Macedonian: Можам да јадам стакло, а не ме штета. Russian: Я могу есть стекло, оно мне не вредит. Belarusian (Cyrillic): Я магу есці шкло, яно мне не шкодзіць. Belarusian (Lacinka): Ja mahu jeści škło, jano mne ne škodzić. Ukrainian: Я можу їсти скло, і воно мені не зашкодить. Bulgarian: Мога да ям стъкло, то не ми вреди. Georgian: მინას ვჭამ და არა მტკივა. Armenian: Կրնամ ապակի ուտել և ինծի անհանգիստ չըներ։ Albanian: Unë mund të ha qelq dhe nuk më gjen gjë. Turkish: Cam yiyebilirim, bana zararı dokunmaz. Turkish (Ottoman): جام ييه بلورم بڭا ضررى طوقونمز Bangla / Bengali: আমি কাঁচ খেতে পারি, তাতে আমার কোনো ক্ষতি হয় না। Marathi: मी काच खाऊ शकतो, मला ते दुखत नाही. Kannada: ನನಗೆ ಹಾನಿ ಆಗದೆ, ನಾನು ಗಜನ್ನು ತಿನಬಹುದು Hindi: मैं काँच खा सकता हूँ और मुझे उससे कोई चोट नहीं पहुंचती. Tamil: நான் கண்ணாடி சாப்பிடுவேன், அதனால் எனக்கு ஒரு கேடும் வராது. Telugu: నేను గాజు తినగలను మరియు అలా చేసినా నాకు ఏమి ఇబ్బంది లేదు Sinhalese: මට වීදුරු කෑමට හැකියි. එයින් මට කිසි හානියක් සිදු නොවේ. Urdu(3): میں کانچ کھا سکتا ہوں اور مجھے تکلیف نہیں ہوتی ۔ Pashto(3): زه شيشه خوړلې شم، هغه ما نه خوږوي Farsi / Persian(3): .من می توانم بدونِ احساس درد شيشه بخورم Arabic(3): أنا قادر على أكل الزجاج و هذا لا يؤلمني. Aramaic: (NEEDED) Maltese: Nista'' niekol il-ħġieġ u ma jagħmilli xejn. Hebrew(3): אני יכול לאכול זכוכית וזה לא מזיק לי. Yiddish(3): איך קען עסן גלאָז און עס טוט מיר נישט װײ. Judeo-Arabic: (NEEDED) Ladino: (NEEDED) Gǝʼǝz: (NEEDED) Amharic: (NEEDED) Twi: Metumi awe tumpan, ɜnyɜ me hwee. Hausa (Latin): Inā iya taunar gilāshi kuma in gamā lāfiyā. Hausa (Ajami) (2): إِنا إِىَ تَونَر غِلَاشِ كُمَ إِن غَمَا لَافِىَا Yoruba(4): Mo lè je̩ dígí, kò ní pa mí lára. Lingala: Nakokí kolíya biténi bya milungi, ekosála ngáí mabé tɛ́. (Ki)Swahili: Naweza kula bilauri na sikunyui. Malay: Saya boleh makan kaca dan ia tidak mencederakan saya. Tagalog: Kaya kong kumain nang bubog at hindi ako masaktan. Chamorro: Siña yo'' chumocho krestat, ti ha na''lalamen yo''. Fijian: Au rawa ni kana iloilo, ia au sega ni vakacacani kina. Javanese: Aku isa mangan beling tanpa lara. Burmese: က္ယ္ဝန္‌တော္‌၊က္ယ္ဝန္‌မ မ္ယက္‌စားနုိင္‌သည္‌။ ၎က္ရောင္‌့ ထိခုိက္‌မ္ဟု မရ္ဟိပာ။ (9) Vietnamese (quốc ngữ): Tôi có thể ăn thủy tinh mà không hại gì. Vietnamese (nôm) (4): 些  世 咹 水 晶  空  害 咦 Khmer: ខ្ញុំអាចញុំកញ្ចក់បាន ដោយគ្មានបញ្ហារ Lao: ຂອ້ຍກິນແກ້ວໄດ້ໂດຍທີ່ມັນບໍ່ໄດ້ເຮັດໃຫ້ຂອ້ຍເຈັບ. Thai: ฉันกินกระจกได้ แต่มันไม่ทำให้ฉันเจ็บ Mongolian (Cyrillic): Би шил идэй чадна, надад хортой биш Mongolian (Classic) (5):  Dzongkha: (NEEDED) Nepali: म काँच खान सक्छू र मलाई केहि नी हुन्‍न् । Tibetan: ཤེལ་སྒོ་ཟ་ནས་ང་ན་གི་མ་རེད། Chinese: 我能吞下玻璃而不伤身体。 Chinese (Traditional): 我能吞下玻璃而不傷身體。 Taiwanese(6): Góa ē-tàng chia̍h po-lê, mā bē tio̍h-siong. Japanese: 私はガラスを食べられます。それは私を傷つけません。 Korean: 나는 유리를 먹을 수 있어요. 그래도 아프지 않아요 Bislama: Mi save kakae glas, hemi no save katem mi. Hawaiian: Hiki iaʻu ke ʻai i ke aniani; ʻaʻole nō lā au e ʻeha. Marquesan: E koʻana e kai i te karahi, mea ʻā, ʻaʻe hauhau. Inuktitut (10): ᐊᓕᒍᖅ ᓂᕆᔭᕌᖓᒃᑯ ᓱᕋᙱᑦᑐᓐᓇᖅᑐᖓ Chinook Jargon: Naika məkmək kakshət labutay, pi weyk ukuk munk-sik nay. Navajo: Tsésǫʼ yishą́ągo bííníshghah dóó doo shił neezgai da. Cherokee (and Cree, Chickasaw, Cree, Micmac, Ojibwa, Lakota, Náhuatl, Quechua, Aymara, and other American languages): (NEEDED) Garifuna: (NEEDED) Gullah: (NEEDED) Lojban: mi kakne le nu citka le blaci .iku''i le se go''i na xrani mi Nórdicg: Ljœr ye caudran créneþ ý jor cẃran.

Comment: Humm you need to executequery("SET NAMES utf8");   before your insert query.

Answer (score 0):

Add following lines in `my.ini` file which is under MySQL installation directory.

```
[mysqld]                     # already exists
max_allowed_packet=1024M     # just add this line, you can set size whatever you want.

# Also set this
default-character-set=utf8
```

You have to restart mysql service.

Check [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/packet-too-large.html)

Comment: @JAVAGeek did you restart MySQL Server?

Comment: what is type of column you are inserting? which version of mysql are you using?

Comment: If we have 4-byte characters (legal in Unicode and Java, illegal in MySQL 5), it throws `Data truncation: Data too long for column` error when we try to insert data. This is an issue reported in MySQL Bugs list http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25666

Comment: `How to check that my UTF-8 data is all 3-byte Unicode?` Errr, no. UTF-8 characters are of variable length, from 1 to supposedly 6 -- but I think 4 is the practical max.