# SphinxQL Data too long for column

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql

I'm inserting data into a Sphinx RT index using SphinxQL, which is working fine.  Just occasionally I get really large values in my dataset and I get the following error:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'title' at row 1
 at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3564)
```

Is there a way to extend the length of the field? or another column type I could use? Failing that, what *is* the length of the field, so I can truncate my data?

this is what my index looks like:

```
index example
{
      type              = rt
      path              = /var/sphinxsearch/example
      rt_field          = title
      rt_attr_timestamp = timestamp
}
```

Comment: Sphinx is 2.0.5. I'm not using MySQL; SphinxQL is a a MySQL-binary-compatible server.  The setting in sphinx.conf is "mysql41".  It could be a Unicode thing - I still don't know how to determine the column size but I will attempt "INSERT IGNORE" (from the last answer to your linked question).  You should put your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I put my above comment into an Answer:

What version of MySQL are you using? What version of Sphinx? Maybe you're facing a Unicode encoding issue similiar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73109/mysql-data-truncation-error)?

Maybe you could catch the Exception, log the offending SQL query. Perhaps the problem becomes apparent once you see the query.