# How can I fix: Data too long for column Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, mysql-workbench

I am working on a moving a legacy system from MS VBA to a Spring-boot desktop application. I try deleting a table and then rebuilding it. The original schema to construct the table structure includes:

```sql
SET SQL_MODE='';
```

Which turns off the strict SQL mode and truncating data will not produce errors.

The Insert query that I intend to run, does finish in MySQL with 65 warnings for data truncation. But when I use the following in my repository class:

```java
@Repository
public interface OrderbookRepository extends JpaRepository<Orderbook, Integer>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {
@Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = rebuild_orderbook , nativeQuery = true)
    void rebuildOrderbook();
}
```

where `rebuild_orderbook` is the Insert query, i get the following error:

```
2019-10-18 16:42:24.285  WARN 4200 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 1406, SQLState: 22001
2019-10-18 16:42:24.285 ERROR 4200 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Data truncation: Data too long for column 'Pack' at row 59
2019-10-18 16:42:24.289 ERROR 4200 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement] with root cause

com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlDataTruncation: Data truncation: Data too long for column 'Pack' at row 59
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3971) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2487) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2079) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2013) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5104) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1998) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.20.jar:na]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy192.executeUpdate(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.NativeSQLQueryPlan.performExecuteUpdate(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:194) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.executeNativeUpdate(SessionImpl.java:1373) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.executeUpdate(SQLQueryImpl.java:373) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.internalExecuteUpdate(QueryImpl.java:405) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:61) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$ModifyingExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:238) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:85) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy567.rebuildOrderbook(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at app.kristom.service.impl.OrderBookServiceImpl.rebuildOrderbook(OrderBookServiceImpl.java:281) ~[classes/:na]
        at app.kristom.controller.OrderbookController.rebuildOrderbook(OrderbookController.java:50) ~[classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_211]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_211]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_211]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_211]
```

How can I supress this exception?

Again, this query works in MySQL where I have disabled strict mode. Also this insert query takes about 75 seconds to execute on MySQL workbench. But when I run it in the application, it termintes with an error after 70-75 seconds. I believe it raises an error after executing the query and when it finally finishes, it throws that error.

Given the circumstances that I cannot change the structure of the database and cannot increase the size of the columns, what can I do to fix this?

Similar questions:

- [Data too long for column Caused by: org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58459188/data-too-long-for-column-caused-by-org-springframework-dao-dataintegrityviolati)

Comment: Have you checked out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73109/mysql-data-truncation-error

Comment: Thanks !! I just need to use 'INSERT IGNORE' instead of 'INSERT'

Comment: Please post this as the anwer